# Routing sound to Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to route my phone sound to Bluetooth Headset. Client has directed to use iBluetoothA2DP interface. But using a2dp.connectSink() asking for write_secure settings permission which is not available.

Please suggest me a  way in case iBluetoothA2Dp is not possible.

Here is my code

```
    private IBluetoothA2dp getIBluetoothA2dp() {
    IBluetoothA2dp ibta = null;

    try {
        Class<?> c2 = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");

        Method m2 = c2.getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
        IBinder b = (IBinder) m2.invoke(null, "bluetooth_a2dp");

        Class<?> c3 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.IBluetoothA2dp");

        Class<?> c = c3.getDeclaredClasses()[0];
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);

        m.setAccessible(true);
        ibta = (IBluetoothA2dp) m.invoke(null, b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast("IBluetoothA2dp: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ibta;
}
```

Here is what i m doing

```
   private void connectA2dp(boolean connect)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connect)
                a2dp.connectSink(device);

            else
                a2dp.disconnectSink(device);
        } 

        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The compiler is telling me to include write_secure _settings permission which I can't use as Android not give access to it.